# AVAssetExportSession works on iPad, no audio on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avassetexportsession, avasset

I have the exact same code running on both the iPad and iPhone versions of my app and the code works fine on the iPad (the video is being exported properly with audio), but the exported video on the iPhone doesn't have any sound. I even ran the iPhone version on the iPad and it worked fine, which means that nothing should be wrong with the code itself.

Any insight on why the iPhone isn't exporting the video with audio would be much appreciated.

I have done some research and somebody mentioned that memory issues could be causing some export problems. The memory and CPU usage are fairly high during the video processing/exporting, but never high enough to receive a memory warning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you stepped through the code (line by line) on the iPhone, setting breakpoints, watching each variable to make sure the value is correct, etc. This would be the first step.